# Where is the secret key for the standalone network?

Tags: stellar-core, testnet, private-network

I am running the docker [quick start](https://hub.docker.com/r/stellar/quickstart/) image for a standalone private test net. I have the network up and running, but I cannot find the secret key for the single funded test account.

Where can I find this secret key? It is not in my logs.

I have seen some answers saying to run stellar-core --newdb, but I do not have the stellar-core command, nor have I seen any documentation on where to download or be able to use the stellar-core cli command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the JS-SDK you can do the following:

```
Network.use(new Network(“Standalone Network; February 2017”));
Keypair.master().secret(); // your secret key
```

Answer (score 1):

The secret seed for the master account is the sha256 hash of the network passphrase. e.g. `"Standalone Network ; February 2017"`.

```
KeyPair.fromSecretSeed(sha256(passphrase.getBytes(UTF_8)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Which libraries are you using for the getBytes method and the UTF_8 variable?

Comment: These are Java methods taken from the Scala SDK source. Which language are you targeting?

Comment: I am targeting javascript

Comment: A potential starting point? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861828/java-string-getbytesutf-8-javascript-equivalent

Comment: Yea i've been trying to make it work. There is no fromSecretSeed method, but fromSecret seems to only want a string and the solution provided returns a list.

Comment: The passphrase is "Standalone Network ; February 2017" so if you have the genseed from that offhand... that works too!